# Eclipse Android Emulator doesn't connect to internet

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have created an app that uses a web-service (from www.worldweatheronline.com) to acquire certain information but it seems that it doesn't have access to the internet and I get "Unfortunately, Browser has stopped". I say this because when trying to use the emulator's browser it doesn't respond at all and I have tried to use Additional Emulator Command Line Options: -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

I have also added internet permissions to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: have you added internet permission in manifest

Comment: yes I have added that as well

Comment: post your log cat then

Comment: don't need to post logcate since the emulators own browser isn't working so lets start from that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proxy setting in your emulator,probably proxy is blocking your internet connection. Try this

1. Go to setting in Emulator
2. Open Internet Setting, and create a new APN
3. Over proxy and Port just enter the proxy settings you are using (e.g setting from IE)
4. Choose this APN, and you are good to go.

Comment: I did this with an ip and a port and also with the the IE configurations but none worked

Answer (score 0):

To check internet connection. Try this sample code-

```
boolean b_IsConnect = isNetworkAvailable();
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
```